# How to read the Transaction from SQL Server Transaction Log

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is it possible to read tracks transactions and changed data from the transaction log file?

Comment: It's a proprietary binary format. What do you want to actually do?

Comment: actually i need some thing like CDC (change data capture) but i don't want to set CDC and wants to read from transaction log

Comment: What are your actual constraints? Why don’t you want to use CDC? You could use transactional replication.

Comment: as mater of in fact we used one ERP and the database of ERP is SQL server ERP engines change table drop table and recreate and lots of work that we don't know so we need read change from transaction log

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use:

```
Select * FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
```